# Spring is not hitting ControllerAdvice in integration tests

Tags: java, spring

I have `webAppContextSetup` through which I set the application context.  Some answers suggest the `standaloneSetup` that has a setter to add my ControllerAdvice class.

I tried other answers where some had suggested to add ComponentScan to test config. However that didn't work for me.

While debugging the test the code doesn't hit the handler. But when I check the UAT logs the handler is hit.

Can someone please help? I'm on my mobile so couldnt add code. This is not a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@WebMvcTest(*Your class name here.class*)`?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(*Your class name here.class*)
public class ExceptionHandlerIntegrationTest {
    ....
}
```

When you run a test class with these annotations the class should start through spring boot and configure any settings automatically, avoiding any extra configuration (ComponentScan etc).

It would help if you attatched some source code but I'm guessing this could solve your problem, Im assuming your using Junit as a runner for this so these annotations wont work with other frameworks most likely.

I used this to test an exception handler class in my api and it worked nicely.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not a Spring Boot application.  I will be attaching source.

Comment: Ah ok thats more tricky then, spring certainly makes things easier.